# C# dynamic method - Field getter with "Object" return type

Tags: c#, cil

i need to get the field as type of "object".

This is the IL of the method:

```
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

What should i add to cast to object.

Thanks to online C# to IL tools if field was value type i must add

```
OpCodes.Box
```

but what if field wasn't value type.

should i get field type and create two seperate dynamic method for reference type fields and value type fields.

Another question :

how can i destroy dynamic method and recreate it. (life cycle?)

Comment: Is the property's type `object`?

Comment: what do you mean => propertys' type `object`?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think by "Field getter" you mean property getter? If so, what is the type of the property?

Comment: If you mean field type. my field can has any type.

Comment: Let's put it this way: Are you trying to build a property getter dynamically?

Comment: Exacly, this is a getter. but this getter must return `object`.

Comment: Then you need to box if the field's type is a value type, otherwise you don't. But you don't need to write another method, you can add a condition checking the field's type and emitting an `OpCodes.Box` is needed.

Comment: Concerning your question #2, you need to unload the appdomain to destroy dynamically created items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to box value type results, for instance:

```
public void EmitFieldGetter(ILGenerator gen, FieldInfo field)
{
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);

    if (field.FieldType.IsValueType)
    {
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Box, field.FieldType);
    }

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
}
```

Comment: My problem solved with answer of  second question, i need a way to temporarily create a method and remove it after some seconds and recreate, but it sound like it will add new layer of complexity to my program, i prefer super slow GetValue with FieldInfo instead. Anyway thanks

Comment: I think `box` requires the value type as the argument.